# When the market is volatile, relatively fewer factors suffice for a productive stat -arb signal. Have you noticed it, and why would that be?

Tags: statistics, arbitrage

In volatile markets only a small number of factor are sufficient for factor based statistical arbitrage to work well. This is an empirical observation. Why would this be? Have others noticed it as well?

Comment: This question has two upvotes, more than most on QF. // In an orthogonal factor model, the factors are independent. It is unlikely several independent factors increase in volatility at the same time.  Large volatility induces large moves in asset prices. Not every asset price "lands" where it should after a big move, a good environment for statistical arbitrage.  In contrast, without volatility, asset prices are closer to equilibrium, and there are fewer big displacements from equilibrium to exploit. Few factors are required because the large scale common factor moves matter, the rest is noise

Comment: the moral police continues to be insistent on 'how the question needs details and clarity', while thanks to @krkeane I got a very reasonable answer. The rest can look for details and clarity.